# select from table where col_a in() ONLY where col_b value matches

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to constuct a single query that fetches certain rows based on *column a* (parameter_id), but ***only*** where the fetched results have a matching *column b (dimension_id)*.

**Here's a table representing the one I'm using.**

```
parameter_dimension
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| id    | parameter_id  | dimension_id   |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| 500   | 1             | 100            |
| 501   | 1             | 101            |
| 502   | 1             | 102            |
| 503   | 2             | 102            |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
```

If I write

```
SELECT *
FROM parameter_dimension
WHERE parameter_id IN (1)
GROUP BY dimension_id
```

I get as desired

```
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| id    | parameter_id  | dimension_id   |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| 500   | 1             | 100            |
| 501   | 1             | 101            |
| 502   | 1             | 102            |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
```

But if I write

```
SELECT *
FROM parameter_dimension
WHERE parameter_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY dimension_id
```

Then I only wish to get the rows that have **dimension_id** in common.
Like so

```
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| id    | parameter_id  | dimension_id   |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
| 502   | 1             | 102            |
+-------+---------------+----------------+
```

**Is it possible to achieve that, and with only one query?**

I prefer to use *IN()* since the number of *parameter_id*'s may vary.

I've searched far an wide, either left with explanations that I could not decipher, and more often than not in doubt that the questions asked were at all related to mine.

Comment: "SELECT *" and "GROUP BY" don't play nicely together, so first figure which columns you actually want returned.

Comment: @Strawberry I see your point. My final query however, will be specific. I appreciate appreciate that you pointed this out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use group_concat with distinct value. you should order by parameter_id

```
 SELECT *
    FROM parameter_dimension
    WHERE parameter_id IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY dimension_id
    having group_concat(distinct parameter_id ORDER BY parameter_id ASC)='1,2'
    order by parameter_id
```

Comment: @Strawberry you can check i have done it out side and it will work

Comment: @Strawberry now will it work ? i have just edited my ans check it

Comment: I think `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT parameter_id) = 2` is the more conventional approach.

Comment: @Strawberry I tried to replace the 'having' line from Knowledge....'s query with yours, I couldn't get it to work. Am I using it wrong?

Comment: @vincibleVince Yes. Self-evidently, you're using it wrong. Beyond that, I cannot say, as I can't hack your terminal, and I can't read your mind!